# Convert 16-bit floating point to 32-bit floating point

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

I have two different DSPs:

- The first one outputs 16-bit floating point value where there is a bit for the sign, 7 bits for the integer and 8 bits for the fractional part.
- The second considers floating point as 32-bit value where there is a bit for the sign, 8 bits for the integer and 23 bits for the fractional part.

I would like to convert the output of my first DSP in the 32-bit floating point format used by the second DSP. Is there any API in C ?

Comment: Not in standard C, no. Perhaps the compiler vendor for the 16-bit platform provides some utility library or something, this seems like a common requirement. Also as pointed out by others, those sound like fixed-point numbers rather than floats. Your terminology is off ,"fractional part" is typically used for fixed point.

Comment: where did you find a 16 bit floating number ? I suppose the lib you use has something to convert it.

Comment: These sound more like fixed point rather than floating point formats. If so, you could perhaps use bit shifting and masking to do the conversion.

Comment: There is an option to output "int16.8" , that is why I get 16bit floating

Comment: Your description of the types is inconsistent with how floating point types are specified in the C standard (with a sign, a mantissa, and an exponent).  Your description is more akin to FIXED point types.

Comment: @MartinR No, this is obviously about converting in the other direction.

Comment: @lovehell See [Q number format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)), if that seems to match what you have, you're golden.

Comment: @MartinR Mmm, okay, so it might be a useful reference, but the *question* is obviously not a *duplicate*.

Comment: Yes it is like a Q format.
My first DSP treats int16.8 as an 7-bit integer with 8 bits in fractional part
It sounds like my only way is doing a bit-shifting no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no standard routines for this in C.

If the first DSP format is just Q7.8 as discussed in comments, then you can convert it to floating-point with:

```
#include <stdint.h>
…
int16_t Temp;
memcpy(&Temp, &PlaceWhereDataIs, sizeof Temp);
float Float = Temp * 0x1p-8f;
```

This simply puts the bits into a signed 16-bit integer, then converts it to `float` and scales it for eight fractional bits.

`0x1p-8f` is hexadecimal floating-point notation for a `float` constant with the value 2<sup>−8</sup>. If your compiler does not support that, you can use `/ 256.f` instead of `* 0x1p-8f`.

If your compiler does not support `int16_t`, you can use `short` if it is 16 bits.

If the second is Q8.23, then it can similarly be converted with:

```
int32_t Temp;
memcpy(&Temp, &PlaceWhereDataIs, sizeof Temp);
float Float = Temp * 0x1p-23f;
```

However, its fields of 1, 8, and 23 match the field sizes of the common IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point format, which makes me suspect it is a floating-point format, not a fixed-point format. In that case, you can get it into a `float` with:

```
float Float;
memcpy(&Float, &PlaceWhereDataIs, sizeof Float);
```

If the first DSP format is actually a floating-point format with 1 sign bit, 7 exponent bits, and 8 significand bits, then some work is needed to convert it. Additionally, you will have to supply details from documentation—custom floating-point formats tend to treat subnormals, infinities, and NaNs differently, as well as have non-standard exponent biases.

If both are fixed-point formats, and you can convert the first to the second with:

```
int16_t Temp;
memcpy(&Temp, &PlaceWhereDataIs, sizeof Temp);
int32_t Result = (int32_t) Temp * (1 << 23-8);
```

Comment: I understand your answer, I have found the same explanation on the net, it looks like fine. However I still do not understand something. The first example you wrote is Q7.8 to float. If you multiply the Q7.8 number by 2^-8, you will right sift to 8 bits, right ?
In that case you will lost the fractional part. I do not understand in term of bit operations why temp*2^-8 could give the right floating point value

Comment: @lovehell: `0x1p-8f` is a floating-point constant, of type `float`. In C, when you multiply an integer by a `float`, the integer is converted to `float`, and a `float` result is produced. Floating-point types include an exponent, so they can represent fractions.